# Android search XML based on some condition

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Here is what I am trying : I have a list of names. I want to search an XML file depending on that names.

XML looks like this :

```
    <book>
       <string> book name </string>
       <array>
          <string> Name1 </string>
          <string> Name2 </string>
       </array>
    </book>
```

Now I want to search say "Name1" and if it matches I want to get the name of the book.
Is this possible? If yes can someone provide some code/snippet or maybe tell me the steps how I can do it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the answers. I am using the using the tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) and wrote this method to search the XML.

```
        public List<String> search(String key, String url){

           List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
           XmlParser parser = new XmlParser();
           String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML
           Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
           NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");

           for(int i = 0; i<nl.getLength();i++){
              Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
              NodeList n = e.getElementsByTagName("string"); 
              if(parser.getElementValue(n.item(1)).equals(key) ||
                 parser.getElementValue(n.item(2)).equals(key) ){

                 items.add(parser.getElementValue(n.item(0))); 
              }
            }
           return items;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android has some built-in XML parsing functions. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Basically:

1) Set up an InputStream for the XML content (if you are downloading it, or reading it from a getResources() for example)

2) Set up your parser: `XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();`

3) Start reading the XML in a loop.  When parser.getName().equals("book"), then continue on until you get to your `parser.getName().equals("string")` and save the results of parser.getText();  Then when you continue on and hit `parser.getName().equals("array")` and you continue on again to `parser.getName().equals("string")`, then check the results of parser.getText() to see if it matches your search string.

Clear as mud?

Parsing XML is a lot harder than it was advertised to be 20 years ago or so, but once you understand that the parser reads the XML as it comes in, it makes it a little easier to see the overall picture of how to implement it.  Study up on that link, it gives you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways to parse XML, I suggest you to use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/news/release-1.7.2)

Its really easy to extract data from XML.

```
String html = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\">
<book>
   <string> book name </string>
   <array>
      <string> Name1 </string>
      <string> Name2 </string>
   </array>
</book></xml>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());

    Element book = doc.select("book").first();

    Element bookName = book.getElementsByTag("string").first();

    Elements array = book.getElementsByTag("array"); 

    for (Element e : array.select("string")) {
      //....
    }
```